# The three different positions of "finalement"

Tags: ordre-des-mots, adverbes

The following is part of an email I sent. In another post, I asked about how to express the idea of "after all": [How to express "after all"](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22160/how-to-express-after-all)

After reading Papa Poule’s comment, now I wonder if and how the three different positions of the adverb "finalement" affect the meaning of the sentence?

---

> Il y a cinq mois, je réfléchissais à ce que je commencerais à apprendre comme septième langue. J'hésitais entre le français et l'allemand. Mais il m'a suffi d'un jour pour comprendre que moi et l'allemand, ça fait deux !
>
> - Content de m'être **finalement** tourné vers le français !
> - {Par rapport à} : **Finalement**, je suis content de m'être tourné vers le français !
> - {Ou encore} : Content de m'être tourné vers le français, **finalement** !

---

***Le pourquoi j'emploie l'adverbe « finalement » :***

Ce que je veux dire ici, c'est que **à la fin**, j'ai fini par arrêter mon choix sur le français, après avoir pesé le pour et le contre de ces deux langues. Il ne s'agit pas de prendre la mesure de tout le chemin parcouru (depuis le tout début de mon apprentissage des autres langues étrangères jusqu'à ce que je me sois **enfin** mis au français).

{ Tout en me doutant bien que la nuance entre les trois peut s'avérer ténue... }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the difference lies in what is modified by *finalement*. In the first case, it modifies *tourner vers le français*, so it means that after some time, you chose French.

On the other hand, if it is in initial (or final) position, it modifies the whole sentence, and in that case I would understand that at first you weren't happy you chose French, but that after some time, your opinion changed and that now you are glad you chose it. By the way, I suspect that the same distinction exists in English.